# FluentNHibernate Automapping Many-To-Many with interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate

I could not find how to set up NHibernate with automapping conventions to detect my many to many relationship in the particular case where I'm using interfaces in references instead of concrete class. Notice that this work perfectly with One-To-Many and Many-To-One case.
Well for instance I have two entities:

```
    public class Model4 : ModelBase, IModel4
    {
        public Model4()
        {
            Model5s = new List<IModel5>();
        }

        public virtual ValueInt D { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<IModel5> Model5s { get; set; }

    }

    public class Model5 : ModelBase, IModel5
    {
        public Model5()
        {
            Model4s = new List<IModel4>();
        }

        public virtual ValueInt E { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<IModel4> Model4s { get; set; }

    }
```

where the interfaces are defined as:

```
    public interface IModel4 : IModelBase
    {
        ValueInt D { get; set; }
        IList<IModel5> Model5s { get; set; } 
    }

    public interface IModel5 : IModelBase
    {
        ValueInt E { get; set; }
        IList<IModel4> Model4s { get; set; } 
    }
```

I'm using conventions for references to translate the interface into class implementation when mapping:

```
public class ReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        Type instanceType = instance.Class.GetUnderlyingSystemType();

        if (instanceType.IsInterface)
        {
            // Assuming that the type starts with an I get the name of the concrete class
            string className = instanceType.Name.Substring(1);

            instance.CustomClass(instanceType.Assembly.GetType(
                instanceType.FullName.Replace(instanceType.Name, className)));
        }

        instance.Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

I would expect NHibernate to detect the model4 <-> model5 many-to-many relationship and to call my ManyToMany convention:

```
 public class ManyToManyConvention : IHasManyToManyConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
        {
            //this code is not reached when using references through interfaces
        }

    }
```

NHibernate will never call the Apply method of ManyToManyConvention in the case I'm using references with interfaces (IList and IList).

However, if I use concrete implementation (IList and IList) the Apply code is called and the mapping is done as expected.

Do you know where I'm missing something in my conventions of where I'm wrong?